# Is it possible to dynamically change the workspace paths in a Team Build definition?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a dev branch and a main branch--obviously both have the same relative paths. Is it possible to use one build definition across both branches and dynamically change the path in the build definition file?

Answer (score 1):

From your question I assume that the TFSBuild.proj is in a folder that is not branched.
Instead I use to branch also the folder with the buid script, that is the folder is *under* the Main trunk. In that way you have a "copy" of the same script under the Dev branches. Then I just have various Build definitions that may point to the "right" copy.